# A problem on verification of a topological space and its convergent sequences

Tags: general-topology

Show that $(X,T)$  is a topological space where $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $T$ consists of all the sets of the form $A\cup B$ where $A$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $B$ is a subset of irrational numbers.
Show that no sequence can converge to an irrational number except an eventually constant sequence.

---

I have no clue how to solve this problem.please help.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Show that if $x$ is irrational, then $\{x\}\in T$. Thus, if $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $x$, there must be an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n\in\text{what?}$ for all $n\ge m$.